# Winform chart label wrong position

Tags: forms, winforms, charts, label, bar-chart

[image]

See Image. The £12,845.63 is 1st columns label. I've tried running below code on a blank, fresh chart, with all default settings (white background too) it does the same thing.

I'm populating chart like this:

```
        private void InitializeData()
    {
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        double i = 0;
        double spacing = 0.1;
        foreach (DataRow rows in DailyBarChartT.Rows)
        {
            Series series = chart1.Series.Add(rows[0].ToString());
            series.Points.AddXY(i, rows[1]);
            series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            series.LabelFormat = "C";
            series.LabelForeColor = Color.White;

            i = i + spacing;
        }
        chart1.Update();
    }
```

I'm guessing the number doesn't fit above the blue bar? how could I fix this? 
I've tried setting label margins to 0 and a few other things.

EDIT:
[image]

setting my "spacing" variable to 0, sets the label to correct position.
How can I have it in a correct position with spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new series for every value, which is not how you are supposed to do it. The spacing works properly if you make one single series for all values.

Quick sample code (works on default chart):

```
        string[] values =
        {
            "12845.63", "1174.89",
            "344.04", "180.83",
            "82.50", "55.00" 
        };

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Black;
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        Series series = new Series();
        series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        series.LabelFormat = "C";
        series.LabelForeColor = Color.White;

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var pointIndex = series.Points.AddY(value);
            series.Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel = "Custom label for each value here";
        }

        chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

Comment: My Legend contains people names. I don't think I can do that with 1 sieries.

Comment: There is a property for that, namely "AxisLabel", I've updated my answer. @Edgaras

Comment: This solved the issue, however, I lost my "Legends" on the top right corner and colourings, all bars are in the same colour. From 1 problem to another.